# Subtract Date field from previous row, reset when value in other field changes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a SQL script that accomplishes the following:

Creates a column which subtracts the value in the Date Field from the value in the Date field from the previous row. This should reset and start over when the ID field changes.

The OpID and Resolutiondate field are fixed, and I am trying to create a column like the one see below.

[image]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results also help.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. I have added the database. I believe I have added sample data and desired results, but let me know if that doesn't suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag()`.  Date/time functions are notoriously database-specific, but the idea is:

```
select t.*,
       (datefield - lag(datefield) over (partition by id order by datefield)) as diff
from t;
```

Comment: lag() is a super useful function! Thank you!